# Determine $f'(4)$ for $f(x)=4e^\frac{\ln (x-3)}{24x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Determine $f'(4)$ for $f(x)=4e^\frac{\ln (x-3)}{24x}$

What I've done is used quotient rule inside the experiential power, but I don't think that's right.

Please Help!!!

Comment: Please show what you have, it is much easier to give help then.  Maybe what you have is right.  $e^{\ln ()}$ should prompt you to simplify before taking the derivative.

Comment: Using the notation $\exp(x)=e^x$, it sounds like you're saying you found $4\exp\left(\dfrac{d}{dx}\dfrac{\ln(x-3)}{24x}\right)$.  If so, yes, that's wrong.  See the chain rule.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Yes that is what I've been doing since I've thought it might be easier to solve if I simplify it

Comment: @John: I don't really understand your comment.  What I'm saying is that method is wrong, regardless of how you simplify. The derivative of $g(h(x))$ is not equal to $g(h'(x))$.  The chain rule says the correct way to differentiate a composition of functions.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=4e^{\frac{\ln(x-3)}{24x}} \iff\ln f(x)=\ln4+\frac{\ln(x-3)}{24x}=\ln4+\ln(x-3)\cdot\frac1{24x}$$

Differentiating wrt $x$ using [Product rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) we get $$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac1{24x(x-3)}-\frac{\ln(x-3)}{24x^2}$$

Now,  as $\ln1=0$

$\displaystyle\frac{f'(4)}{f(4)}=\frac1{96}$ and $\displaystyle f(4)=4e^0=4$

Comment: One shouldn't use logarithmic differentiation provided the basis is $e$.  It's a sort of ... useless.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe, we can always apply logarithm whenever powers of terms and/or product of terms to make things more clear

Comment: Sure you can do it when there are powers, $f(x)=x^2$, e.g.  Then $\ln\bigl(f(x)\bigr)=2\ln(x)$ hence $f'(x)/f(x)=2/x$ from which we achieve $f'(x)=2x$, but I doubt it makes things more clear, don't you?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe, I do as the power of $e$ here is complex enough. But. at the same time I do admit that here we could safely avoid logarithm as well

Comment: As Ross showed above, $f(x)=4(x-3)^{1/24x}$. That's a case where one urgently should use logarithmic differentiation. --- And I wonder why you use the product rule instead of the quotient rule.  Your approach could be much simplified.